# @media in css3 only works for first selection

Tags: css, media-queries

My CSS is supposed to cause three different background colors based on size:

```
@media all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 880px) { 
    body {
        background:#F69;
    }
}

@media all (min-width: 341px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background:#06F;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 340px) {
    body {
        background:#000;
    }
}
```

This code only changes the background color for the first size range. Why? How can I make it work for all three ranges?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You're only supposed to get one colour. Your media queries are setup correctly. The background colour will be different for different screen resolutions. Try using a different browser.

Comment: hi there! I tried in safari, FF and chrome...and it doesnt make the job? any thoughts?

Comment: I found the answer my self. If you are going to set up different actions the limits in between the widths must follow  one after another....ex: 0- @media screen and (max-width: 499px), 1 -@media all and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 699px) 2-@media all and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1200px) and so on.  :)

Comment: @YoniGeek: Could you post that as an answer so that you can mark it as the solution?